# Interfaces in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to use interfaces in c++ like in java or in c#. I decided to use purely abstract classes with multiple inheritance, but something is terribly wrong when I specialize the interface:

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual int method() = 0;
};

// Default implementation.
class Base: virtual public Interface
{
public:
  virtual int method() {return 27;}
};

// specialized interface
class Interface2: public Interface
{
public:
  virtual int method() = 0;
// some other methods here
};


// concrete class - not specialised - OK
class Class: public virtual Interface, public virtual Base
{
};

// concrete class - specialised
class Class2: public Interface2, public Base
{
};



int main()
{
  Class c;
  Class2 c2;
return 0;
}
```

Warning 1   warning C4250: 'Class' : inherits 'Base::Base::method' via dominance    30

Error   2   error C2259: 'Class2' : cannot instantiate abstract class   42

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why do you not use virtual inheritance for Class2?

Comment: Another question is why are you trying to reimplement Java in C++?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want mixins, where methods in one base class can call methods in another base class, or just "regular" multiple inheritance? If the latter, why use virtual inheritance, and why inherit from both Interface and Base (the latter is sufficient)?

Comment: To be clear: please describe exactly the behaviour you expect for Class and Class2 (e.g. what should happen when method() is called; can a pointer/reference to Interface2 be used to point to an instance).

Comment: If the method is not reimplemented in Class2 or Class (it is not in this case)  Base::method() will be called. Otherwise the reimplementation will be called.

There is an interface hierarchy with a common base dumb implementation.

Comment: Did you consider using pimpl instead of inheritance ?

Comment: @jalf: What sort of a comment is that? The OP's question (though perhaps poorly described) is a genuine technical question that has a reasonable technical answer out there somewhere, and comments like yours don't help anyone.

Comment: @Neil: Virtual inheritance for Class2 itself will not help (or hurt) matters. Virtual inheritance for Interface2 however will prevent creation of two distinct subobjects of type Interface in Class2 (although that won't have any practical consequences if Interface is really a pure interface, lacking members).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I think they help because sometimes the OP should rethink or reconsider his strategy, for his own good. Trying to program in one language with designs tailored for another one is not exactly the best idea. Lots of people have been producing great designs in C++ without worrying about interfaces.

Comment: @Daniel: Interfaces are not a language-specific idea -- they are a general (and powerful) idea that has different names in different languages ("interface" in C#/Java, "abstract base class with no members" in C++). C++, and any self-respecting OO language, should have mechanisms for manipulating them, and I'd like to see comments/answers describing how that can be done, rather than straw-man attacks that misinterpret the word "interface" as something Java-specific.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, ok. I learnt C++. I've been working for about 10 years with this language. Some times (not many) I used pure abstract classes. And guess what, they worked! They worked according to what is specified in the C++ standard. You can't create an instance, you can inherit from them, you can give implementations for the methods - and it works. What I never tried is to mimic the appearance of the code structure and syntax that you have in other languages.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not interested in "mimicking the code structure and syntax" of another language either -- that's my point, people are seeing the word "interface" and freaking out, thinking "OMG he's trying to code Java in C++!!!". Interfaces are a **general** idea. It took me a while to "get" why they are useful because I had to see them in action in a large, complex codebase to appreciate how much they can simplify your life -- but now that I do "get" them, I want to see what we can do with them in C++.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Pure abstract classes and what we can do with them are well known in C++. The OP should have better asked a precise question about the exact problem he's getting. We're not solving a mystery here today; lots of people have used pure abstract classes in C++ before.

Comment: @Daniel: I agree that the question was very imprecise. I think the right way to address that is to ask for more precision, rather than to assume the OP is trying to do something he "shouldn't" be doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heh heh, this problem tickles something buried deep in my head somewhere.  I can't quite put my finger on it but I think it's to do with defining an interface heirarchy and then inheriting both an interface and an implementation.  You then avoid having to implement all functions with by forwarding calls to a base class.  I think.

I think this simple example shows the same thing, but is maybe a bit easier to understand because it uses things that can be easily visualized: (please forgive the struct laziness)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vehicle
{
    virtual void Drive() = 0;
};

struct VehicleImp : virtual public Vehicle
{
    virtual void Drive() 
    {
        cout << "VehicleImp::Drive\n";
    }
};

struct Tank : virtual public Vehicle
{ 
    virtual void RotateTurret() = 0;
};

struct TankImp : public Tank, public VehicleImp
{
    virtual void RotateTurret() 
    {
        cout << "TankImp::RotateTurret\n";
    }
    // Could override Drive if we wanted
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TankImp myTank;
    myTank.Drive();         // VehicleImp::Drive
    myTank.RotateTurret();  // TankImp::RotateTurret
    return 0;
}
```

TankImp has essentially inherited the Tank interface and the Vehicle implementation.

Now, I'm pretty sure this is a well known and acceptable thing in OO circles (but I don't know if it has a fancy name), so the dreaded diamond thing is ok in this case, and you can safely suppress the dominance warning because it's what you want to happen in this case.

Hope that somehow helps point you in the right direction!

BTW, your code didn't compile because you hadn't implemented the pure virtual "method" in Class2.

**EDIT:**

Ok I think I understand your problem better now and I think the mistake is in Interface2.  Try changing it to this:

```
// specialized interface
class Interface2: public virtual Interface // ADDED VIRTUAL
{
public:
    //virtual int method() = 0;   COMMENTED THIS OUT
    // some other methods here
};
```

Interface2 should not have the pure virtual defintion of method, since that is already in Interface.

The inheritance of Interface needs to be virtual otherwise you will have an ambiguity with Base::method when you derive from Interface2 and Base in Class2.

Now you should find it will compile, possibly with dominance warnings, and when you call c2.method(), you get 27.

Comment: Yes, the point is that I do not want to implement the method in class2. I want to inherit the base implementation. Your example is unfortunatelly unrelated to my situation.

Comment: Bingo! This is the answer I was looking for! Conclusion: using *virtual* inheritance *does* allow methods to be "blended" in C++. danatel: Please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: To summarise: the problem is that there are two distinct Interface subobjects in the definition of Class2 as it stands -- one from Base, one from Interface2. Making Interface2 inherit virtually from Interface collapses these two subobjects into one, eliminating the ambiguity of calling "Interface::method()".

Answer (score 5):

Class2 inherits from an abstract class (Interface2) but does not implement the pure virtual method, so it remains as an abstract class.

Comment: The method is implemented in Base. Base brings default implementation. Interface2 is specialized Interface. Imagine Interface = Protocol, Interface= TCP/IP protocol,  Base - contains  support methods. Class is an http server.

Comment: Yes, but it is not implemented in Interface2. If they do different things, then they probably shoudn't have the same name.

Comment: Interface never implements anything. It is just a statement that certain methods are available. For example Interface can do method(), method2() and method3(). Interface2 brings method4() and method5(). There may be many implementations of both Interface and Interface2. Base usually contains trivial operations which can be reused by the whole hierarchy.

Comment: @danatel, Tom means that the implementation Base::method() is not automatically "used" by Class2 as an implementation of Interface2::method(), so you need some extra syntax to have this effect. This is probably so to avoid accidental interface... sorry, pure abstract class... method implementations due to random name clashes caused by inheriting from another concrete class.

Comment: Agree. So far it looks like this is impossible to do in c++. See Pieters answer and j_random_hackers comments.

Answer (score 4):

Based on this comment

```
If the method is not reimplemented in Class2 or Class (it is not in 
this case) Base::method() will be called. Otherwise the reimplementation 
will be called. There is an interface hierarchy with a common base 
dumb implementation. 

– danatel 16 mins ago
```

That's not what you got, you don't have a common base, you've got

```
Interface -> Interface2 -> Class2
Interface -> Base -> Class2
```

The interface is not 'merged' in the derivation tree, interface2 does not inherit virtually from interface, so it'll have its own interface super class.
It's like the pure virtual `method()` exists twice in Class2, once implemented via Class, and once not-implemented.

And even if you had inherited virtually, the common base (Interface) still would not have an implementation

If Base contains trivial operations that should be usuable in the whole hierarchy, then why not have Base as your startpoint? (even if still pure virtual with an implementation).

If this was just a very simple example to make the question short, something like the [Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) might be more usefull. But it's hard to guide you further without knowing more.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. It describes why my approach is probably  not viable in C++. I like the word "merged", it exactly describes what I want. I hoped that virtual multiple inheritance will do this for me.

In the end I will probably end with an non-abstract hierarchy with Base as the root like you suggest, loosing all  the advantages of purely abstract interfaces.

Comment: Good points, and perhaps Base could be made the root class in this instance, but there are cases when that would be a bad idea -- e.g. if Base introduced member variables. In that case, making Base the root would forever tie derived classes to carrying these members around, even if they were never used. Remember, Base just contains stuff that is *often convenient* -- but it's not *necessary* for implementing a Interface.

Comment: NOTE: markh44's excellent answer shows that by using *virtual* inheritance, methods *can* in fact be merged in C++.

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding `Class`:** All you need to do is derive `Class` from `Base` -- the fact that it implements `Interface` is implied, and in fact, inescapable:

```
class Class: public Base  // virtual inheritance is unnecessary here
{
};
```

`Class` will inherit `method()` from `Base` as desired.

**Regarding `Class2`:**

**Disclaimer: Negative result ahead**

Based on your comment on [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806561/interfaces-in-c/806604#806604), I **thought I had** the answer for `Class2`:

```
// concrete class - specialised
class Class2: public Interface2, public Base
{
public:
    using Base::method;    // "Imports" all members named "method" from Base
};
```

But actually, this doesn't work.  Grovelling through the C++ standard reveals that 
section 7.3.3, paragraph 14 explains that `using` can't be used to resolve ambiguous accesses to inherited members:

> ... [Note: because a using-declaration designates a base class member (and not a member subobject or a member function of a base class subobject), a using-declaration cannot be used to resolve inherited member ambiguities. ...]

It seems that the only way to get the desired behaviour in `Class2` is to manually forward the method:

```
// concrete class - specialised
class Class2: public Interface2, public Base
{
public:
     virtual int method() { return Base::method(); }
};
```

**Regarding `virtual` inheritance:** You *don't* need it for `Class`'s declaration, but you probably *do* need it for `Interface2`'s declaration to ensure that `Class2` only has a single subobject of type `Interface` -- as it stands, every `Class2` object has two subobjects of this type.  (Although that won't cause problems if `Interface` is in fact a pure interface, lacking member variables.)  If it helps, draw a diagram: every time a base class appears without the keyword `virtual`, it appears as a distinct object; all base classes that appear with the keyword `virtual` are condensed into one object.

**[UPDATE: [markh44's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806561/interfaces-in-c/807643#807643) shows that the above approach (of making `Interface2` inherit *virtually* from `Interface`) will in fact allow `Class2` to automatically inherit the implementation of `method()` from `Base`!  Problem solved!]**

Comment: Thank you. Class always got compiled. I added Class just to show, that in C++ abstract interface works when the interface is used directly. When there is an hierarchy of interfaces, base methods are not merged from the second level of hierarchy.

Comment: You're welcome. Your comment's a good summary of the issues BTW.

Answer (score 3):

You should also look at defining a virtual destructor in your Interface if you might be deleting using an Interface or Base pointer.

Without a virtual destructor you will have problems if you do something like:

```
Base *b = new Class2();
delete b;
```

Comment: ++1 This will cause you all kinds of headaches.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Existence of virtual destructors is known to me, I just wanted to make the example short.

Comment: That's good to hear. Just making sure as it can trip people up if they're not aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3783768&postcount=6) in a different forum seems to tackle the exact problem you mention.

Comment: In my case, A and B have the same common base. C inherits directly from  B  and indirectly from D which inherits from A having the same abstract interface as A.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid the diamond inhertance pattern:

```
            Interface
            /      \
          Base   Interface2
            \      /
             Class2
```

This will cause you call kinds of grief down the road if you're not careful. Ambiguity will bite you.

In your specific instance there's no need for Interface2 to inherit from Interface. Interface2 doesn't need to specify "method" since it's abstract. Remove the inheritance between Interface and Interface2 to break the diamond. Then you're hierarchy looks like:

```
        Interface                Interface  Interface2
           |                          |       |
          Base                      Base      |
           |                           \      /
         Class                          Class2
```

And your implementation looks like:

```
// concrete class - not specialised - OK
class Class: public Base
{
};

// concrete class - specialised
class Class2: public Base, public Interface2
{
    virtual int method() {return 35;}

    virtual void Inteface2Method { ... }
};
```

Comment: OK, I agree it's generally a good idea to avoid the DDD, but what if Interface2 is really a superset (superinterface) of Interface? Are you really saying that there is no way of representing this relationship in C++?